# How to initiate multiple instance of an app developed through py2app

Tags: python, macos, setup.py, py2app

The app that I built using py2app has a program argument which is the file name. For e.g a text file name that has to be opened using TextEdit. I installed my app in /Application location. When I open any file my double-clicking it, my app comes into action and then opens the file with default file opener. But the issue is that multiple instance of myapp is not generating, when I want to open two files at a time. I checked the activity-monitor. In windows, using py2exe, when I open two files at a time, two process of my app is activated. 
My setup.py file is:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP=['myapp.py']
DATA_FILES= [('',['config.cfg','server.pem','success.html'])]
PACKAGES = ['keyring.backends']
OPTIONS={'iconfile':'cc.icns','packages': PACKAGES,'argv_emulation': True,'plist':{'CFBundleShortVersionString':'4.0','LSBackgroundOnly':True},}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
    )
```